# Как создать декоратор на typescript для слежения за изменениями?

Tags: typescript

Я хочу, как только значение изменится - отправить его в webworker для хранения "базы данных" в другом потоке.
Просто подписаться на Observable или передать значение по ссылке я не могу.

Хотел бы что-то такое....

```
@WebworkerParam('SECTIONNAME-PARAM1')
public MyParamSection1Param1 = new BehaviourSubject('my Value');

@WebworkerParam('SECTIONNAME-PARAM2')
public MyParamSection1Param2 = 'содержимое';
```

Как подвязаться на значения через декоратор и

1. Как происходит .next() на стриме - то связаться с функцией `sendToWebWorker('SECTIONNAME-PARAM1', value)`
2. и так же для обычных переменных.

Comment: Я не совсем понял проблему, но вдруг не видели https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-decorators-in-typescript

Comment: что здесь понимается под "изменением значения"?